# Using a Fetched Results Controller for 1 single entry in CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a swift (or iOS in general) question:

**My scenario:**

I have a table that has avatars (among other things) in each cell. Each avatar has a presence (available/unavailable). The datasource for the other content in each cell is not backed by CoreData (this is a limitation) and there's no relationship to the user (which *is* in CoreData) that provides the avatar photo and presence.

So I made my avatar be a view that takes a user and then presents the user's photo and presence. When the presence changes for the user (which is in CoreData), the view needs to be notified so it can update the presence indicator on the avatar. (Don't worry about my code structure here, I'm using MVC but I simplified things to avoid a long description of my scenario).

**My question:**

Is it bad to use `NSFetchedResultsController` (FRC) to observe 1 single entry in CoreData? Is there something else better suited for this (since `NSFetchedResultsController` is really suited for table views)?

Basically what I would do is have the avatar use an FRC to listen for changes to its user in CoreData. So each avatar in each cell would have an FRC that observes 1 user. It seems odd to me to use an FRC that way. (Don't worry about cell reuse, when the avatar is disposed on cell reuse, all the FRC would be disposed too).

**Other options:**

I could set up an observer (a delegate) on my users CoreData storage manager object to listen for changes to a particular user (the storage manager is used to update the entries in CoreData so all updates to the CoreData user entity go thru that) and then when the observer hear's of a change, it could notify its delegate associated with that user (which would be the avatar). But that would essentially be like making my own FRC. And that would get complicated with cell reuse in the table (since each avatar is in a cell in a table) because I would have to register / unregister delegates often I think.

I could listen on the user storage's MOC for any notifications about changes (like `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange`), but then I would get changes for *every* user and have to filter. And again, I feel like this would be similar to reimplementing the FRC, but less efficient probably, and I would probably also run into the cell reuse complexities.

**Summary:**

I just want advice on the best way to listen for changes to a unique (by user ID) entry in the database. Is the FRC the best way, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to the User model object, you can KVO on its properties.